# Make the selected object to be highlighted in outliner

Tags: outliner

I have a complex object structure where there is multiple nested object. If the outliner structure is collapsed, How to show the selected object , so the outliner will expand itself recursively to find/highlight that object ?

The fastest way is to find the object's name and type in search box. But is there any hotkey so i can do it directly from 3d viewer ?

Answer (score 5):

The hotkey <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> might be what you're looking for, the Outliner follows the same Show Active behavior that the 3d Viewport does, while the cursor is in either pane.

This also works for bones in armatures, you'd press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> once to target the armature, then again to open the tree and highlight the selected bone.